# Manage Team member capacity for users in multiple Teams

Tags: tfs

We are currently working on how to best manage our projects in TFS 2012. We are planning to create **multiple team in order to manage concurrent iteration** on the same project for distinct feature not released at the same time so we did two team (Project 1, Project 2).

The problem we currently have is how can I manage team member capacity when assigning a member to multiple Team. Is ther a way to view **Capacity assign to a member for all current iteration of every team** without navigating between multiple sprint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not supported with the current tools, nor have we plans as for now to support this in the near future.

Feel free to add your suggestion to [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com). We use that list to help prioritize our work.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is provided out-of-the-box and has been available since TFS 2008. You will require to install Microsoft Project Server onto the SharePoint implementation that you use with TFS (or another one if you like) and then configure the integration.

> By installing Team Foundation Server Extensions for Project Server, project managers can use Microsoft Project Server to access up-to-date project status and resource availability across agile and formal software teams who work in Team Foundation.  This integration enables data to flow from work items in Team Foundation Server (TFS) to tasks in enterprise project plans in Project Server. Project managers and software development teams can use the tools that they prefer, work at the level of precision that supports their needs, and share information transparently. After the two server products are configured, the synchronization engine maintains scheduling data and resource usage for the configured data in the mapped enterprise project plan and team project.

For TFS 2010 there is an Add-on, but for TFS 2012 it is included in the product.

- [Enable Data Flow Between Team Foundation Server and Microsoft Project Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg455680.aspx)
- [Microsoft® Team Foundation Server® 2010 and Microsoft Project Server® 2010 Integration Hyper-V Virtual Machine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22267)